# How does the kohein gadol's substitute wife work?

Tags: marriage, yom-kippur, kohen-priest, divorce, masechet-yoma

The first mishna of Yoma<sup>1</sup> explains that before Yom Kippur, a substitute wife is prepared for the kohein gadol lest his wife die -- because the torah says he makes atonement for himself and "his house", and "his house" means his wife.  But he has to be married to exactly one woman on that day because it says "house", not "houses".

The g'mara on 13a-b describes a system of conditional gittim (bills of divorce), but I'm having trouble understanding how this actually works.  Do I understand correctly that he takes an additional wife before Yom Kippur, with gittim written such that he will be married to exactly one woman when he performs the avodah?  If so, does it have to be a different wife each year because of the laws of divorce and kohanim?

Since he could (in an unfortunate turn of events) end up married to the substitute, it seems like everyone involved would want to take as much care with this match as with any other.  Yet, finding a good (and different) shidduch every year seems challenging, perhaps burdensome, especially as each must be a [betulah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0321.htm#13).  Is that just part of the cost of being kohein gadol, or am I misunderstanding this g'mara?

<sup>1</sup> in the Bavli.  The Yerushalmi understands this as a conditional marriage to the second woman rather than a conditional divorce (h/t Fred), which would reduce but not eliminate the problem.

Comment: Incidentally, while this follows the Bavli's interpretation of Rabbi Yehuda's opinion (the rabbis do not agree that a substitute wife should be prepared for the kohein gadol), the Yerushalmi explains Rabbi Yehuda's opinion as requiring a conditional marriage for the second woman, not a conditional divorce (*Yoma* 1:1, מקדשין לו אשה אחרת על תנאי שמא יארע דבר באשתו שנאמר וכפר בעדו ובעד ביתו ביתו זו אשתו דברי ר' יהודה ). I presume that this would allow the same woman to conditionally marry on an annual basis.

Comment: @Fred How many years would she hang around as a Betulah for?  There was probably a very high turnover.

Comment: @DoubleAA If they actually ever used substitute wives, and did so according the Yerushalmi, then probably yes. But perhaps every 3 or 4 years rather than annually.

Comment: The cynic's answer: this sounds like a second Temple innovation, so practically speaking, it could have been every year, since the Kehunah Gedolah was sold.

Comment: (Side point, I'm not convinced that as much care was taken with matches back then as it was nowadays. For the high priest, it could have been as simple as 1. She's from a good family lineage-wise,  2. She's a virgin, 3. There is a mutual attraction, and 4. Make it work.)

Comment: @Fred, she would be a Besula for 6 months in her lifetime http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=27&perek=17&halocha=13&hilite=

Comment: @Yishai Only the Kiddushin needs to happen while she's a Betulah IIRC. They could Mekadesh her Al Tenai that he needs her at any time before she gets otherwise married, for example.

Comment: @DoubleAA, if the purpose of the Tenai is to say he is not married to her (so he only has one wife at the time of the Avoda) then how could the tenai take effect after her נערה window closes?

Comment: @Yishai You mean if she is needed in future years it would retroactively mess up the Avoda in previous years? Ok, I hear.

Comment: @Yishai That's a good point; maybe they would need a new backup wife annually even according to the Yerushalmi's view of Rabbi Yehuda. On the other hand, if Rabbi Yehuda agrees with Rabbi Shimon and Rabbi Elazar in *Yevamos* 6:4, he would hold the age limitation doesn't apply. (Even though the Rambam does not rule like R' Shimon and R' Elazar, perhaps he also does not rule like R' Yehuda about the requirement of a backup wife. See *Hil. K'lei HaMikdash* 5:10, which may be understood to imply this).

Comment: I've never quite understood why the Kohen Gadol wasn't just married to two different women permenantly, if this was a requirement of his avodah....

Comment: @Yishai Also, the need for a backup wife is conspicuously absent from the Rambam (*Hil. 'Avodas Yom HaKippurim* 1:[2](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=9033)-[3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=9034)), suggesting he does not rule like Rabbi Yehuda.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a precautionary marriage which is unlikely to actually continue and, in the unlikely event it did continue but didn't work out, they could always get a divorce. They also likely had a very different cultural expectation from marriage back then that didn't require the same level of agonizing. Finally, it sounds a lot like the *gemara* a few *dapim* later (Yoma 18b; see also Yevamot 37b) where a temporary, formal marriage was created for a compelling need, without an extensive preliminary courtship.

Comment: The problem in the question was not just the conditional wife, but with the "conditional gittin" from Yoma 13a-b; namely, that the KG's wife may become forbidden to him because of ריח הגט (+), and then he'll have to find a new wife every year. Your point of "very different cultural expectation from marriage" might help this question anyway, though.

Comment: @Shokhet Did not notice the reyach haget concern in the OP's question (though did wonder about it myself). Nonetheless, if the marriage was in line with what seems to be the final understanding of the marriage on 18b, that shouldn't be a problem since it's in name only and could indeed be repeated with someone new (and willing) annually.

Comment: @Shokhet I suppose your question does stand regarding his real wife if she also required a conditional get that triggers the psul kehuna... Is it clear Rabbi Yehudah holds of reyach haget in such a case?

Comment: @Shokhet On second thought the Mishan in Gittin (81a) is pretty explicit:  "ובית הלל אומרים: אף על פי שנתנו לה על תנאי ולא נעשה התנאי - לא פסלה מן הכהונה"