# How was a standby wife chosen for the Kohen Gadol during Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, mishna, kohen-gadol

According to R Judah's comment in the Talmud he says seven days before Yom Kippur a standby wife was chosen for the Kohen Gadol

Tractate Yoma, [Daf 2a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.2a.1-2?lang=bi)

CHAPTER I

MISHNAH:

> SEVEN DAYS BEFORE THE DAY OF ATONEMENT THE HIGH PRIEST WAS REMOVED FROM HIS HOUSE TO THE CELL OF THE COUNSELLORS AND ANOTHER PRIEST WAS PREPARED TO TAKE HIS PLACE IN CASE ANYTHING HAPPENED TO HIM [THE HIGH PRIEST] THAT WOULD UNFIT HIM [FOR THE SERVICE].
> R'JUDAH SAID: ALSO ANOTHER WIFE WAS PREPARED FOR HIM IN CASE HIS WIFE SHOULD DIE.

How was she chosen and what category was used to select her?

Comment: With the same criterions as the first wife

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%92

Comment: The Talmud continues: "What if the second wife dies too?  *En l'davar sof* -- there is no end to the matter".  But it does not answer the question.

Comment: possible duplciate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33333/759

Comment: I don't understand the problem. All marriages were arranged those days.