# May a woman think about another man during relations?

Tags: halacha, women, sexuality, kavana-concentration

I understand the talmud says that a man may not think about another woman during marital relations, does the same prohibition apply to the woman?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you would include a citation of where the Talmud says this law fro a man. If you don't know, then including as much information as possible about where your understanding comes from could help others track it down.

Comment: This is a specific case of [this related question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40861), and it is answered there.

Comment: @Fred thanks, didn't see that. you can delete this question

Comment: This may have been prompted by a recent podcast claiming the gemara about women leaving the mikva and gazing at Rabbi Yochanan's handsome countenance (*B'rachos* 20a, *Bava M'tzi'a* 84a) meant that the women were fantasizing about R' Yochanan when they were with their husbands (though this is contrary to the rabbinic understanding of maternal impression, and would be prohibited by the sources cited in my linked answer). It's unclear whether the podcast also understood the incident with Rava as involving fantasizing (*K'subos* 65a), in which case that would also be incorrect.