# Books of the Ben ish chai on a husbands responsibilities to his wife

Tags: jewish-books

In hukai hanoshim chaper 9 he writes that he will in a different book bring the husbands responsibilities to his wife.
Did he do it?
If yes in what book/s?

see bottom paragraph
[image: see bottom paragraph]

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62635

Comment: He wrote of lot of [books](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93%D7%90%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.95) - wouldn't suprise me if it were in one of them like מים חיים - מוסר והשקפה.